# What's the name of the song from My Hero Academia season 3 episode 9?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

It's the song that plays around 3:50 of s3 e9. I know it's been played on the show before. Another episode it was in was season 3 episode 1 when Todoroki was reminiscing at the pool. I believe I heard it before that as well. It is pretty soft and has a woman in the background.

Comment: Could you specify an exact time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing against Episode 1 of Season 3 around 15:55, I believe it's included in the soundtrack for Boku no Hero Academia 2, Disc 2, Track 5: Kimi wo Koete (君を超えて).

Answer (score -1):

my hero academia s3 OST - "the power of all for one"

Comment: Actually the first person was right. The song I was looking for was 君を超えて (Kimi wo Koete). But thanks for answering. I do  like “The Power of All for One” too.